# Grails DataSource db2 issue : connection closed

Tags: gradle, db2, datasource, grails-2.3

In my grails application (Grails 2.3.8), apart from grails default GANT, I am using Gradle 1.7 as building tool.

In this app, I have used two databases, which are connected with separate drivers. One is Oracle and other one is IBM DB2.

While starting my app in server, both db connections are working fine, but after sometime (around 1hr) DB2 connection is throwing error like : `Connection Closed.`

The complete exception stack is as follows :

```
2014-07-17 08:55:27,860 [http-0.0.0.0-8585-3] ERROR transaction.JDBCTransaction  - Could not toggle autocommit
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlNonTransientConnectionException: [jcc][t4][10335][10366][3.66.46] Invalid operation: Connection is closed. ERRORCODE=-4470, SQLSTATE=08003
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.dd.a(dd.java:731)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.dd.a(dd.java:60)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.dd.a(dd.java:120)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.Connection.checkForClosedConnection(Connection.java:5720)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.Connection.setAutoCommit(Connection.java:1095)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:80)
    at $Proxy19.setAutoCommit(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy$LazyConnectionInvocationHandler.invoke(LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.java:375)
    at $Proxy20.setAutoCommit(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy$TransactionAwareInvocationHandler.invoke(TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy.java:239)
    at $Proxy20.setAutoCommit(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.toggleAutoCommit(JDBCTransaction.java:224)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.rollbackAndResetAutoCommit(JDBCTransaction.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.rollback(JDBCTransaction.java:192)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doRollback(HibernateTransactionManager.java:677)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processRollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:846)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.rollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:823)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.transaction.MultiTransactionStatus.rollback(MultiTransactionStatus.java:82)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.transaction.ChainedTransactionManager.rollback(ChainedTransactionManager.java:191)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.rollbackOnException(TransactionTemplate.java:162)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:135)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.support.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:59)
    at com.orbitz.neat.CountryController.index(script14056034110611248237173.groovy)
    at com.orbitz.neat.CountryController.index(script14056034110611248237173.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:953)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:411)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:405)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.MixedGrailsControllerHelper.invoke(MixedGrailsControllerHelper.java:156)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.handleAction(AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.java:354)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.executeAction(AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.java:231)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.handleURI(AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.java:197)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.handleURI(AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.java:121)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleGrailsController.handleRequest(SimpleGrailsController.java:72)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.GrailsDispatcherServlet.doDispatch(GrailsDispatcherServlet.java:355)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:277)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:276)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:309)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:56)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:189)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor215.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:277)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:276)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:309)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:250)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:56)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor237.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:277)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:276)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:309)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:250)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:56)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor237.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:277)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:276)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:309)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:250)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:56)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor237.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:277)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:276)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:309)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:250)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:56)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.access$000(ApplicationDispatcher.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher$PrivilegedForward.run(ApplicationDispatcher.java:80)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:294)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(WebUtils.java:332)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(WebUtils.java:297)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(WebUtils.java:288)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter.UrlMappingsFilter.doFilterInternal(UrlMappingsFilter.java:217)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor237.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:277)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:276)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:309)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:250)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:56)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsPageFilter.executeFilterChainWithWrappedResponse(GrailsPageFilter.java:233)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsPageFilter.obtainContent(GrailsPageFilter.java:208)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsPageFilter.doFilter(GrailsPageFilter.java:153)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:277)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:276)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:309)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:250)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:56)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor237.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:277)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:276)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:309)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:250)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:56)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor237.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:277)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:276)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:309)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:250)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:56)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor215.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:277)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:276)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:309)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:250)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:56)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:652)
    at com.orbitz.container.app.application.tomcat.valves.HttpShutdownHookValve.invoke(HttpShutdownHookValve.java:21)
    at com.orbitz.container.app.application.tomcat.valves.RequestQueryCheckValve.invoke(RequestQueryCheckValve.java:58)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Is there any way to resolve this connection issue?

Comment: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21647500

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov If that is the way this problem is solved, you should create an answer.

Comment: Just not quite sure that it's relevant to this particular case. Author should try log size manipulations and see if it helps

Comment: That url is describing the issue. But I need to save the log also.

Comment: There are many reasons why a connection can be closed, including firewall timeouts, connection pool idle timeouts, DB2 configuration settings as shown by @KonstantinV.Salikhov, DB2 WLM policies, network outages etc. You need to investigate further. Start by looking at the `db2diag.log` contents at the time you think the connection was closed. Note that the DB2 driver only detects if it's closed when you try to use it, so in your case it was closed at some time _before_ 2014-07-17 08:55:27,860

Comment: @mustaccio if continuous db hit is coming, db connection is not getting closed. I think it is getting closed by the idle stage.

Comment: where will be this log file db2diag.log added?

Comment: `db2diag.log` is usually located in the directory `sqllib/db2dump` under the instance home directory on the DB2 database server.

Comment: I can't find such a file. Is there any config codes for logging db2 ?